# How can I switch 2 characters in vi?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vi

I like the fact that I've memorized <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> for switching two lines (i.e. <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> deletes the line and then <kbd>p</kbd> puts it back '1 higher').

Is there are similar set of keystrokes for switching 2 characters so that `wsih` would become `wish`?

Comment: Line swapping, character swapping and word swapping tips in vim can be found at [vim.wikia.com](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Swapping_characters,_words_and_lines).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer turned out to be `xp`, just not the windows kind ;)

If you are working on your vim skills generally you may also find this useful:

[How to automatically strip trailing spaces on save in Vi and Vim?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75430/vi-vim-how-to-automatically-strip-trailing-spaces-on-save)

Comment: Yes, `xp` transposes two characters in vi.

Comment: `x` - eat the character under the cursor (and put it in the paste buffer); `p` - paste the buffer after the position of the cursor (which has advanced one character in the text).

Comment: Just curious. What's the "windows kind"?

Comment: @sch http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/products/windows-xp

Comment: or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP

Answer (score 2):

`xp` will swap current character with next character.

We can do another kind of swap, `Xp` will swap current character with previous character.