# How to automatically strip trailing spaces on save in Vi and Vim?

Tags: vim, vi, editors, vimrc, whitespace

Is there a `.vimrc` setting to automatically remove trailing whitespace when saving a file?

Ideally (to be safe) I would like to only have this functionality for certain files, e.g. `*.rb`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This works (in the .vimrc file) for all files:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e
```

This works (in the .vimrc file) for just ruby(.rb) files:

```
autocmd BufWritePre *.rb :%s/\s\+$//e
```

Comment: This solution's nice, but I think @Sukminder's solution below is better, because it repositions the cursor correctly.

Comment: What does that the lastet `e` use?

Comment: @acgtyrant I tested with and without the 'e'. It seems to be what keeps Vim from spitting an error when you save a file that doesn't have any trailing whitespace. In other words, when the pattern can't be matched, Vim spits an "E486: Pattern not found" error and the 'e' seems to be what suppresses it since you don't really care in this case.

Answer (score 31):

To keep cursor position use something like:

```
function! <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
    let l = line(".")
    let c = col(".")
    %s/\s\+$//e
    call cursor(l, c)
endfun
```

else cursor would end up at beginning of line of last replace after save.

*Example*: You have a space at end of line `122`, you are on line `982` and
enter `:w`. Not restoring position, would result in cursor ending up at beginning of line `122` thus killing work flow.

Set up call to function using `autocmd`, some examples:

```
" Using file extension
autocmd BufWritePre *.h,*.c,*.java :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()

" Often files are not necessarily identified by extension, if so use e.g.:
autocmd BufWritePre * if &ft =~ 'sh\|perl\|python' | :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces() | endif

" Or if you want it to be called when file-type i set
autocmd FileType sh,perl,python  :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()

" etc.
```

One can also use, but not needed in this case, [getpos()](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#getpos%28%29) by:

```
let save_cursor = getpos(".")
" Some replace command
call setpos('.', save_cursor)

" To list values to variables use:
let [bufnum, lnum, col, off] = getpos(".")
```

Answer (score 3):

My [DeleteTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967) does this and, in contrast to the various simple `:autocmds` floating around, also handles special cases, can query the user, or abort writes with trailing whitespace.

The plugin page contains links to alternatives; there's also a large discussion on the [Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces).